# Increase size of html special characters (&#183;) in an input placeholder

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, input-field

I have a bit of an odd request. I'm creating a form on WordPress using the plugin Gravity Forms. I would like to add a bullet point to the end of my placeholder. The only way I was able to do this is to put the special HTML character `&#183;` in the placeholder field on the plugin which is a middle dot. It works, but the dot is pretty small and I would like to increase its size.

Here is what the plugin placeholder field looks like:

[image]

I tried to wrap the special character with a `<span>` with a class so I can edit it in CSS, but when I click save, the plugin automatically removes the `<span>` tags.

Here is a screenshot on what the plugin spits out on the site:

[image]

I would like to make that dot much larger.

Here is the HTML that the plugin spits out:

```
<input name="input_1" id="input_1_1" type="text" value="" class="medium" placeholder="Name ·">
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Maybe some jQuery will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the password dot (`&#9679;`) or bullet (`&#8226;`) instead.

**See the following comparison / examples:**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="middledot &#183;"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="bullet &#8226;"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="password dot &#9679;"/>
```